# Converting wave to vector and vice versa creates noise

Tags: neural-network

I’m a long time data scientist that works mainly with texts. I’m now trying to apply my knowledge into voice and I’m struggling with some simple tasks in python.
As far as I understood I can manipulate voice (converting voice to vectors for neural networks) using mfcc of the voice file.

However, when I try to convert it back to voice I got tons of noise.
My pseudo code:

```
class wav2vec:
    mfcc = None
    org_shape = None
    wave_shape =  None
    sr = None

max_len=50
feature_dim_1 = 20
channel = 1
feature_dim_2 = 50 
filename = 't1.wav'


def wav2mfcc(file_path, max_len):
    wave, sr = librosa.load(file_path, sr=None)
    mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(wave, sr=16000)
    org_shape =  mfcc.shape

    if (max_len > mfcc.shape[1]):
        pad_width = max_len - mfcc.shape[1]
        mfcc = np.pad(mfcc, pad_width=((0, 0), (0, pad_width)), mode='constant')
    else:
        mfcc = mfcc[:, :max_len]

    objWav2vec = wav2vec()
    objWav2vec.mfcc = copy.deepcopy(mfcc)
    objWav2vec.result = copy.deepcopy(mfcc)
    objWav2vec.org_shape = org_shape
    objWav2vec.wave_shape = wave.shape
    objWav2vec.sr = sr
    return objWav2vec

def mfcc2wav(objWav2vec, file_path, max_len):
    mfcc = objWav2vec.mfcc.reshape(objWav2vec.org_shape[0],max_len)
    mfcc = mfcc[:, :objWav2vec.org_shape[1]]
    n_mfcc = mfcc.shape[0]
    n_mel = 128
    dctm = librosa.filters.dct(n_mfcc, n_mel)
    n_fft = 2048
    mel_basis = librosa.filters.mel(objWav2vec.sr, n_fft)

    bin_scaling = 1.0/np.maximum(0.0005, np.sum(np.dot(mel_basis.T, mel_basis),axis=0))

    recon_stft = bin_scaling[:, np.newaxis] * np.dot(mel_basis.T,invlogamplitude(np.dot(dctm.T, mfcc)))

    excitation = np.random.randn(objWav2vec.wave_shape[0])
    E = librosa.stft(excitation)
    recon = librosa.istft(E/np.abs(E)*np.sqrt(recon_stft))

    librosa.output.write_wav(file_path, recon, objWav2vec.sr)

t = wav2mfcc(filename,max_len)
t.mfcc = t.mfcc.reshape(1,feature_dim_1, feature_dim_2, channel)
mfcc2wav(t, 't2.wav', max_len)
```

Can anyone explain why I don’t get the same sound as the original file?